# How to find a object of a list in a text

Tags: python

The goal is finding any object of a list in a users input. In context, I am trying to find any letter in a string of numbers. My "solution" is to have a list of every letter of the alphabet then searching through a text finding any object of the list.

Problem being, I am extremely unknowledgeable and don't know how to do it. I suppose using "find()" would work, though am unable to make this work either.

```
def Main():
  text = input("Enter Algorithym \n")
  count = 0
  for x in alphabet:
    found = text.find(alphabet.count)
    if found != "-1":
      print(count)
      count += 1

  Main()  ## Main Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could import re to find the letters in the string as follows:

```
import re

# Define a string of numbers
string_of_numbers = '1234abc5678def'

# Use regular expressions to find letters in the string
letters_found = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', string_of_numbers)

# Print the letters found in the string
print(letters_found)
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to loop through you can use isalpha:

```
# Define a string of numbers
string_of_numbers = '1234abc5678def'

# Loop through each character in the string and check if it is a letter using isalpha()
letters_found = [char for char in string_of_numbers if char.isalpha()]

# Print the letters found in the string
print(letters_found)
```